# Comparison geodesic lengths

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold of curvature $K$ where
$k\leq K\leq 0$, for some negative number $k$.  Is there an explicit formula describing the difference between

- $
  d_g(x,y)
  $ and
- $
  \|Log(x,x_0)-Log(y,x_0)\|,
  $
- $d_H(Exp^H(z,Log(x,x_0)),Exp^H(z,Log(y,x_0)))$

where $x,y,x_0\in M$, Log is the Riemannian Log map on $M$, $Exp^H$ is the Riemannian exp map on the hyperbolic space $H^d$of same dimension as $M$, $z$ is an element of $H^d$ and $d_g$, $d_H$ is the metric induced by $g$ and the hyperbolic metric respectively?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation ${\rm Log}$ here... I'm guessing that it means the only vector ${\rm Log}(x,x_0) \in T_{x_0}M$ such that $\exp_{x_0}({\rm Log}(x,x_0)) = x$, is that it?

Comment: Exactly (assuming that this vector does uniquely exist of course)

Comment: At least if $M$ is complete, we have $$d_g(x,y) \leq d_g(x_0,x) + d_g(x_0,y) \leq \|\log_{x_0}x\| + \|\log_{x_0}y\|.$$For example, if $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to M$ is the geodesic such that $\gamma(0) = x_0$, $\gamma(1) = x$ and $\gamma'(0) = \log_{x_0}x$, then $L[\gamma] = \|\log_{x_0}x\|$. It's also easy to see that $\|\log_{x_0}x\| = \|\log_{x}x_0\|$, but I'd need to think more for better results.

Comment: True, but quick question why is the right most inequality not a strict equality?

Comment: It could be that $\gamma$ actually realizes $d_g(x_0,x)$. Think collinear points in $\Bbb R^n$...

Comment: Ah OK. I see your point